# SAS data mining

Tags: sas, extrapolation

I have a dataset with ID & a Good/Bad indicator variable:

```
ID   Good_Bad
734374  0
4834110 1
```

I want to extrapolate the 1's 12 times as 0s so that for every 0 I have 12 1s like this:

```
ID  Good_Bad
734374  0
4834110 1
4834110 1
4834110 1
4834110 1
4834110 1
4834110 1
4834110 1
4834110 1
4834110 1
4834110 1
4834110 1
4834110 1
```

& this has to be done using SAS. Can anyone help out?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data want;

set have;

if      good_bad = 0 then output;
else if good_bad = 1 then do;
  do i = 1 to 12;
    output;
  end;
end;

drop i;
run;
```